# Problema para cambiar a php7

Tags: php, apache, xampp

Acabo de intentar cambiar en XAMPP la versión de PHP a PHP7 siguiendo unas simples instrucciones de este vídeo.
[Actualizar o cambiar version php](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtQ-6vkQRRo)

Yo tengo la misma arquitectura X86 en php por lo que he descargado la misma versión que se indica en el vídeo que es la version para windows (php-7.2.12-Win32-VC15-x86). Pero algo esta fallando por que al final no arranca Apache y de envía este error.

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
20:17:14  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
20:17:14  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
20:17:14  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
20:17:14  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
20:17:14  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
20:17:14  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

¿Tambien en intentado cambiar la escucha de puertos pero no funciona?¿Como puedo cambiar a php 7? ¿Hay alguna manera más sencilla que no implique instalar de nuevo xampp? 
Gracias por cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Bro te recomiendo como server para desarrollo Laragon, es mucho mejor y puedes trabajar con varias versiones de php, es exageradamente simple cambiarlas alli, en lo personal lo veo muucho mejor que xamp y Wamp

Comment: @CarlosQuintero, Gracias, puede  ser una solución ¿sabes si Laragon es compatible con Xampp? Es decir, ¿puede que haya incompatibilidades con puertos, etc?